# jquery prevent event hander from running using second event handler

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I have a form select box and two 'change' event handlers.

The first handler is bound with:

```
$("form select").change(function() { doStuff1(); });
```

This handler is loaded in an external .js file in the document head and attaches to every select it finds.

The second handler is bound when the page is loaded in a script block and is called immediately:

```
$(function () {

var $myselect = $("#myselectid");

$myselect.change(function (event) { doStuff2(); });

if ($myselect.val()){
    $myselect.trigger("change");
}

});
```

It only attaches to a single select.

The problem is that I need doStuff1 to not be run for myselect when it is manually triggered by my script, but it always is and always runs before doStuff2.

I have tried calling event.stopPropogation() and event.stopImmediatePropagation() but doStuff1 is always called.

How can I prevent doStuff1 being called for my manually triggered event?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/  `trigger()` will let you pass in extra arguments.  You can pass in an extra argument that your binding can look for.  If it is there, and is a value you expect, ignore the execution of doStuff1.

Comment: @Taplar dostuff1 is self-contained.  Unfortunately I can't ignore the effects of calling it.  I need to prevent it being called in these circumstances.

Comment: Right.  What does that have to do with what I said?

Comment: @Taplar Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by 'ignore the execution of dostuff1'  Can you explain more/give an example?

Comment: Ignore, as in, put an if conditional around it so the execution of the doStuff1 does not happen if the extra arguments are given on the trigger call

Comment: @Taplar Thanks. I hadn't realized that the same arguments would be passed to both handlers.  Once I realized that, your suggestion worked.